# Change content style inside iFrame body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have iFrame which looks like this:

```html
<iframe id="iFrame" scrolling="no" name="iFrameTarget">
#document
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <form id="#myForm"></form>
    </div>
</body>
</iframe>
```

and I'm trying to change css style of element inside body `#myForm` I tried this but it didnt help:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('iframe').contents().find("form").first().css('max-width', 'none');
});
```

Is there other solution to do this ?

Comment: Is the iframe content being served from the same domain as the outer page? Also, `none` isn't a valid value for `max-width`. You may want `initial` or `inherit` depending on your HTML structure and goal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: I just checked again the iframe is not from same domain, inherit doesnt work also

Comment: 'the iframe is not from same domain' this is your problem in that case. You cannot amend  the content of a cross-domain iframe for security reasons. What you're attempting to do is not possible.